# Power outage detection to kickstart a safe shutdown and data retention process

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design, current-sensing, data-storage, architecture

I plan a system that operates on a 5v rail.
The power is supplied from an outside DC source.

The 5 V powers an RPI CM4 and other components that are controlled by it.
The whole system requires up to 5 A of power, of which the cm4 requires up to 1.8 A.

I want to implement a power outage mechanism that triggers:

1. Data retention in order to prevent data corruption
2. Cut off power to all components other than the cm4
3. Perform a safe shutdown process (not mandatory)

[image: architecture of power outage detection]

I plan on using a super capacitor  to supply the cm4 in this process and a high- side switch (like the [adp196](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADP196.pdf)) to cut- off power to all other components.
**update:
4.75 V is the minimum operating voltage for the CM4. I need at least 100 ms from trigger to perform the data retention process. I need to ensure that the CM4 is able to draw up to 1.8 A. c= (Dt*I)/Dv = 0.1*1.8/0.25 = 0.72 F (5.5 V rated) **

I also want to place an ideal diode ([LTC4358](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/4358fa.pdf)) on the input 5 V rail in order to:

1. Prevent reverse current consumed from the supercap
2. Keep voltage drop low

Schottky performs poorly in this system's case.

The current sensor needs to trigger the CM4 when the current drops below 50 mA.

This solution is planned by me and I don't have experience in this area.

**Is my solution viable?**

**How can I implement the current sensor?**

Comment: How long does it take the CM4 to get to the desired state after you sense that power is lost? How much current does it need while doing so? I think if you get these numbers and estimate the size of the supercapacitor you may change your entire plan.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson 4.75v is the minimum operating voltage. I need at least 100mS from trigger to perform the data retention process. I need to ensure that the CM4 is able to draw up to 1.8A.  c= (Dt*I)/Dv = 0.1*1.8/0.25 = 0.72F. I have added this calculation to the question

Comment: If you didn't want to reinvent such capability, consider a [UPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply) with shutdown signal output.

Comment: The ideal diode you picked requires 9V min.

Comment: Is your 100 ms (not mS, millisiemens) a measured value? Have you actually tried shutting down your CM4 to see how long it takes? Are you considering that your "5 V" supply may not be providing 5.00 V but might be more like 4.8 V or 4.9 V?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson this is the time required to perform data retention which means flushing all volatile memory to the nonvolatile one. to perform full shutdown i need about 6 seconds and it is not mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in ICs that are specialized for this task. Look for "supercapacitor charger". They often use several capacitors in series and have a status pin that indicates when the main supply fails.

Here is one example: https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc4041.html

Note that I haven't thoroughly checked if it's adequate for your application, this is just an example.

Comment: wow, I have been looking at LTC datasheet for days and didnt run into this one, which seems to fit perfectly.